# How to specify primary key constraints when creating a Delta table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am using something like [this](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/read-csv-schema.html) to create a dataframe. I then save it in a delta table using something like the following.

```
diamonds_with_schema.write.format("delta").saveAsTable(saveLocation)
```

My question is how can I make a column as primary key. Also, how to make a clustered primary key with two or more columns.

Comment: There's no primary keys concept. What you could do to improve performance is running [Z-Ordering | multi-dimensional clustering](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-optimize.html)

Comment: But online tables require a primary key in databricks so surely there must be no?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Databricks` there is a partial solution.  There is a `primary key` support in Public Preview [Declare primary key and foreign key relationships](https://docs.databricks.com/tables/constraints.html#declare-primary-key-and-foreign-key-relationships)

> Primary key and foreign key constraints are available in Databricks Runtime 11.1 and above.

> Primary key and foreign key constraints require Unity Catalog and Delta Lake.

> You can use primary key and foreign key relationships on fields in Unity Catalog tables. Primary and foreign keys are informational only and are not enforced. Foreign keys must reference a primary key in another table.

> You can declare primary keys and foreign keys as part of the table specification clause during table creation. This clause is not allowed during CTAS statements. You can also add constraints to existing tables.

```
CREATE TABLE T(pk1 INTEGER NOT NULL, pk2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT t_pk PRIMARY KEY(pk1, pk2));
CREATE TABLE S(pk INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                fk1 INTEGER, fk2 INTEGER,
                CONSTRAINT s_t_fk FOREIGN KEY(fk1, fk2) REFERENCES T);
```

> You can query the information_schema or use DESCRIBE to get details about how constraints are applied across a given catalog.

> https://docs.databricks.com/tables/constraints.html

> Informational primary key and foreign key constraints encode relationships between fields in tables and are not enforced.

Comment: Is there no way of doing this in pyspark as well?

Comment: @DanielWyatt  afaik no: referential integrity is not a native pyspark/spark sql thing